# Error when deserializing an object with a List<T>

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have been spinning my wheels on this and I do not see an error in the code but the JSON.stringify result looks wrong to me, but I doubt the browser is returning an incorrect result so I have no ideals left on where to check or things to try.

Error:

```
Error converting value "[see below]" to " to type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JsonModels.AccountItemModel]'. 
Path 'Items', line 1, position 6923.
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
    var myobj = {};
    myobj.Items = [];
    jQuery('select[Name="j_id0:SiteTemplate:j_id12:j_id26:j_id37"]').children('option').each(function() {
        var NewObj = {};
        NewObj.AccountId    = makeid(25);
        NewObj.AccountName  = makeid(100);
        myobj.Items.push(NewObj);
    });
    return JSON.stringify(myobj);
})();
```

c# Code

```
var task = mainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync(script, scriptUrl: mainFrame.Url).Result;
if (task.Success)
{
    try
    {
        Logger.Trace($"RawResult: {task.Result}");

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModels.AccountItemResponseModel>(task.Result.ToString());
        TotalAccountsToProcess = result.Items.Count();
        Logger.Trace($"TotalAccountsToProcess: {TotalAccountsToProcess}.");
        AccountsToBeRead.AddRange(result.Items);
    }
    catch (Exception ix1)
    {
        Logger.Fatal(ix1, "PopulateAccountList Exception p4.");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Models:

```
public class AccountItemModel
{
    #region Public Properties

    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    #endregion Public Properties
}

public class AccountItemResponseModel
{
    #region Public Properties

    public List<AccountItemModel> Items { get; set; }

    #endregion Public Properties
}
```

Data:

```
{"Items":"[{\"AccountId\": \"3O3RlhdhhzqWrQm1hCF1EoYpi\", \"AccountName\": \"MB6rsTTr7tUt74ccUnW2MS3pKta39wQuUaeKN1grgioqK4hI5D85eaiOwpXPdFecjZ2cIPaE7EZdTksA0ciWUvQk8eL18lu9EMzP\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"IvgAC4sYQTQ9NNJ8yBIsXaLst\", \"AccountName\": \"6xLU2M1gdGamb5oLQAAxhFQyBF8UrYn9WYiD4j7DA1lHUnwx01DDoK46IZqd0YSJT88AH5Z1JS8OQLx4Wb6TLfrQFglR21NlIQsz\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"vyrOHwHSwK1o4CPQ9IEP39Fyp\", \"AccountName\": \"Xg9mcZ0AxmtUS67bP0NSvRnKZsabldiDDKovDcGFYJkcM6yifqrYYmF9kqKH5Fz8C7REs85phuWD4m2kPL1qJJca8Q3svkdnfMiA\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"wIcYnNUNjGDCSfaD0YaQzAR0G\", \"AccountName\": \"177wc3wNIiGBdizzADu700PyltI3jOyHvVfETAWoz95P8hnIgrPswKf6xKEoBRQOjbt5PfTmtFFHxEv2gszcNrs0JfIjFv1yaiou\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"fLVRKU62qYgT5nmYaGrSNBoO8\", \"AccountName\": \"xTeqtRDv22YBJEa0oQJU6JQihfIvU0ywHiJGpd6D3vNYTWzvtpIZELYdsHpMyua9oWLFXpUuDvffhF7HTqrF9GtD9OmKy18aTJUh\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"460sbklroG9jq4BHCmpYEBg09\", \"AccountName\": \"6sLu7TjoZbJd7UKHPZNoBJUqbX7wfiHEvUzAHEIBfKvCG0GLowbXEB98jBP3Jdtzn7yFNAZGPJeEgbynn2Tn410tLsHRBAAmmb52\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"VoAwAepE8Nl2xvQzBS2382gFp\", \"AccountName\": \"JRCkTvrx8SC8S7K5yPltGy0KNWw5DpYzNAN9HiohMcg0OFVxio8JCM2IU2ZlbNYpSa9e9FzO19g3TSo0bovVlP0C6Kwzy3GJQQn7\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"nHLYxbly80bbIqgYEFGcRb3Kd\", \"AccountName\": \"ELFpJ0uuKJgg5nYMyQBFwhwzqX8VrsnWowZkVeSu4OKR7g5721AWYkBbJ8RauIVrXFq1g7iqgzzsOcsKRE1XrYWgnfttdPwne71s\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"uv9iHFJbodmJUhnoQAtLiDtrK\", \"AccountName\": \"4C8PYj6ZLLmkWz34ySVvb6BZZKN3virfyatFar6XmBaJIH9dvZy5xyT7hTZoExv6Cm7Xq9xvx0ndOHy4uXl9eq6JKDz1pos3l7zh\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"oYiHdoKtLkVh3tl0mfUDWrBTS\", \"AccountName\": \"ujpmv5RZ4azFefXJzPiIylHrPclrw5ftU6USj4kuXsO3xVSk8zJ1PR0pObBXoaakZYFSIdP2XRKms9ewHf285kZsu8lT9iunrGxt\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"LP5RQ8eHB5u5nf3hNBUHSswLc\", \"AccountName\": \"mpm4VRhaktsRsaipL2cy5ryJwreUig8PzE1Hc0zZS1SN2QGOve01JTI2ivJ545o1bH7rGy0nihEA7RtAdPPJDDsGCGmK1xGcl3N0\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"SfGZdWKC6LyeQarFvuLTrMtmL\", \"AccountName\": \"V28vnKp4RczlVI0qxFMVcEfrj7tfSh0DC5BoiAx8wSdUNZ8epdapiLEVWcPFkosMJ9ZEJ99pOh2QweqbjkN77AKRVbQyvIRV8p0M\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"FUde1uYkqtjYZAQ3DvV68THK6\", \"AccountName\": \"yVEJavfOaSv2sIQI5UgCUh7rdi8h2tl6qPEqTjLndcY33XwOktFbDojPZgprsz7RJK92urLMPMzQZy5VoS1ivu64l151tSscqEYd\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"6qyrcGz5bnKgKATtajjBT3yFt\", \"AccountName\": \"Uy58tA9VNI9WrIcX6dGidqCRTgXXmZCSnXjia53h055A2OnJhBoLDEKCH8cBZtjb6Z6Vn2ICqB8LUpnlUGre7UdYXpPif8TvQVwA\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"9DqjJxBNVtmNdGusXtW24yaBY\", \"AccountName\": \"RNPMbSecsRon6oO9csAYQZEP67In9P6yLaTuTcDECZKqrQ9MLiOBJrEw9PCasp5uC4oHZftYea7jmgo1J1T4xEFPIz5ILjhR4OF1\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"QSO0mm4GYETtzpMQAQaz39dpi\", \"AccountName\": \"735JP91332WTEXEfToHuNqIzMD4toOjCUiRcOFKYB9k2mVniNqrN9kLSE5O0XOAQoHm0ja3tYPm8eGDuLGFRNI2ZITJj4fZDjI51\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"0Wq6P76nNVprCHI5UR1JWgr4Y\", \"AccountName\": \"hjApFOp9voLOefSyVfZVhcOA2MuGaDm20kMgh8NcGfUhpeXv4T5JSYsAk3pCukIuSoxIliWgw5nxRtdKovwR2UL3dPbajsYOVKvn\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"uxzKcqZPdwzUiUO9I7FhwwmmU\", \"AccountName\": \"1LwmVFIZS64ICOJX13pe9kwztHLRZDoPiQ1j0sxglUT8rzSjqIKcTxNKBXfw6zbgjUct7DX7R8kbL42daOrLZbVenzKkcVTkzd0t\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"UKFHAvjg1Nui6DEbpUoVKHbLo\", \"AccountName\": \"M2WiPRgoaJMo9Prgw8EvB2yA4uG1qTJicWa3ZLB6uM13He9RmgOmyIerlOXj39V8NuZkfR7AsKMGxfTB0gg8EIZWEXeMJg9Aawid\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"DAMposuvLLPwTY3qXdNgedaX2\", \"AccountName\": \"WfvBbPAsmoePVWCczWh0dfKZQlK9c9dG0b5MY5wla9UJDcW1KkZBn91RJSh0sJsmx21CYa11tXSv6ZwmsOe4w8VOYizGLZPr9yUi\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"NJlRXVE5hnLWeX9QPov9zaoxc\", \"AccountName\": \"IuyVQ6TI2rY9WRwLl3KuLkhUehMo6jyDP2WXUNB6smpMLuDCIs6Wyq2EGitnj7Xc5Z6E86Es5uxue0oxBivWPXJFZHhhK1e5wn29\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"hOKA6PC251soOR1g7nNPqjUzK\", \"AccountName\": \"0aMMwfDhs8cAcU8RIqRLlPx45XFC27BbNLWB9fZJ7XbNvTlyNrUwBhw3a0zjMbOOKnIP5qVkAm89BW6GTUUdmDkcvENkshPsgAGd\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"RAnmleoMtGL30OufmRSbXVgyH\", \"AccountName\": \"E3gWhlUw774xWSNxyG0Ywzh6cmszOXELBMXs0uYItA7bZKC6vdiovdYm1mIWZjkbKmIGOJgJ0ZO1GNjZAvGikVpVF1IWpwg9tJwD\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"jS7jx8TkggDmv8E7UzDaFc5TE\", \"AccountName\": \"4YStCcm3jmaITyae5OW0OcyFlQU8asPyydYtwsfERm0R1aKglzNWTazrZ0cC18cZBCYsXkFs5yyI7HC3NoGXrmSKr7YIJPxKIzK1\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"QiMB5SrwDKhW1OMrE4TbfdpAU\", \"AccountName\": \"lJTzjtFRF0rpBSuhym2RbdLyZ2paMqXivI8ba9IUPLKxUvZbWu4u6LmozHkMpy718EQU7zjsV1qMx4y2cw3oGNjUe8wAj96twaip\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"oP1KRoqcyae9708r5RI30ZlPb\", \"AccountName\": \"3az6FzT2qPreZ64NOieRhLHy2J7mzTJVQIENfJjRR5yCKNVQQaSu7DAIrzdiwiJte59Nf9kfFJTBjcO3WZpfGwfsnLqwe3qKO11g\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"cM7VtnzbgPME8f2awF0pE7QyU\", \"AccountName\": \"p15n5dVcqlw42dFTAKjgF7B6E8g6k95hlqgtzlxSqaSpepCpM9fdSJ2ntApWkcHkORnVkIXxcSBYTVm9frUB5FAXAgG21LAHI5dl\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"6CS2YyDQyQs2zNSmiMtUCIPsZ\", \"AccountName\": \"lx3YJ3IejKn9uGcAKQaHC9xOL9LCXzbGRaR0dEf78wX1CPw245ukrGpRghH9XMkJFephSdMvGZxvjEW9fZAz83oKtYpg79XUFOtu\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"X6UedJHy07iVAkmAPA9jN200g\", \"AccountName\": \"NLVWy3DxuwtVs0pOZnvjyI5b8WVFqVB0Gu3d9KxhcvxT0VtAOoD7K2F4jcaaa6t2yqEpbTKgUqpqtXtQ0O2omiFX12lPvBz9wFPv\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"b3XyVzQFj2rrns3qx0ZOychx1\", \"AccountName\": \"pMxDS1h9FSyONeaC8cYDEA7dcrtwzcnRTOwwDmFXAwdZdsmrTwEBRzNGIcbpDJBpFJhTL6eL6t3VZN0zvC4hxEN4JmSO23p2hU5e\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"eXaE87vsepubVJ1zIzuYInmix\", \"AccountName\": \"2da7G5qf0cU6zfUDLo8MzcswVvPXToSiVvozOcMehIdYShzCba45kxnExFn5rFAExF2rLGTzww3jJOFfF4l1sh28EgfRFR9qUQhf\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"cKdL80sMFttp5ErKsm1e9nEBg\", \"AccountName\": \"hbbA0byasvExllqzR6utPxsNjNOkGgd2HI58mzNnJJL9okvxBpLJHDZyMM0kQQEfnRG1E8aenxWGsFqmy4XJDvQ3xECdU678bIUS\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"Z5HnWwFGweGsI5w9w3zX6qG9E\", \"AccountName\": \"ydeAGvMKp1l7MOYpszgR4KmdINTIU2u9zYUbQ2M1YR6WkAtSRYqx61nHPdmph9aAwNKfV26blGgfMZgC8OguPSd0lV4n9GgBihAm\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"WSkDp58ltar8Gou5USLCBqJLV\", \"AccountName\": \"wUWx0caPh5ZntHxT3MhiB9PugTcDBmcSmRyLXrYiBfZZPWv7n89qeIS7V5nIH5nNsefzprbkhTWRLxrmMpVEscF0ASa60KvVTLo7\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"15Ns40cnHYe0A9AKREQ60OKMb\", \"AccountName\": \"WXFpnhG42pkg86VnPjZMwHGIn8yWZ3KPR8NyQjH3YKFMzTsojytw5EMUTFfE8m7A6AYXMNJpHFDqnbh3EiPzPfu8XRHdkUq7yXrS\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"nxSwRKd7tR7YzZZtbplb70bJb\", \"AccountName\": \"pjHmBu5eVCasoo5KEY3jVloNcnpjMY9KDEy05ibJhyE99mHLMWCd4avsyxZb3xqO7CUeS7LZBzp6dpeve4vaZcVnAp5QZ048y4e7\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"Ev1hP7wEJ5Q8WwKhrrxAQYT5i\", \"AccountName\": \"MoHupEDFk1HgWOLSHov9oYdtlvZNBvrEE0oY6xjf3fxZbU2Xl4xMxuputlGtjYhkmVpyjvUWjytwtZxIopNFuA22HahnDatKQo4a\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"ypymBjkGwPxHZTEqDHMBIgJUS\", \"AccountName\": \"vbNxBsStMJWIowgVBXqPsI1unFXrOjX1G61Th9eDMIzgGt0JxlpAKbqulj3ZDyuNl5xMqgY8hGPER9YI13aUp7TwcqqGM5cjza8u\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"GVQ56gL1ccJ5atXE7kM7peN2w\", \"AccountName\": \"x5d4OPUWFXnBhGq2UiNYE2hgvWDlkeill3WgwTtps9YT8fPjOM1bsxtyeE9FOpFnN0sjDApwBWajBh0S8NfKlP1vgMi1tJjx9mtE\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"gquwT7QOmuiKs2NzRkVFsYw6h\", \"AccountName\": \"A2gNMofHqC11WD4abTvKIU2RoXjGPrk0AwMVnTup1hEuzpydYgVRBPScKYvdoienlkhwaydZZjJn9knsfDFulIsTtDiy0A7b3bpa\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"6ef3yRIX4OMPPgA1tDeaW8GDz\", \"AccountName\": \"zpjzYHobfGt9F0xaW4c4sIlEyboJdD5lQUvDM4o8qutNe1OE4BoZUbWlzUrkJjlMKoyaVz9PQiauAmShWXMYC6ymE4GGQVD3ajBA\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"mu8iaBu5SAYMQxVdVtCXcHsBV\", \"AccountName\": \"eJ17K6BCtRbtWtJ1xRlRSp2sAH3VhJgXG4T769w5VjLs9rQnzZgaVqbg5hDdUhVKWIRXuvD7R2aScDwtTyKZ2IUV4djiv8kYIQNZ\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"JVID8ZI6bvcaeD9diLjPO7gIN\", \"AccountName\": \"KnMcOFfE37dafZEa05Dt2kdpuvoRCNPJndYDwgRR78RuYnHlVNLKODRek7vcxErkj3zmu5NxAmKjjnE6JbGVtfvHhZxHM5g3fRan\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"NUag1wRmvYacugJipQDALGDkR\", \"AccountName\": \"bt2uVbLwI3A249MH72WnJfHGyHY091fi2aSqSEwjhpZqGlKRZb0DkVCqYBilsHsjNRM1q7AbJrPh73N109L2YbPMcA1fzYgJtGAQ\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"tHlsGcE0Yq67hQw73sbDVfAGO\", \"AccountName\": \"eAbi61uxE310CcBh2I2d8Rm8xLVTsrvPHTDg7M2a5BFiXq96b9itxk0ECMcx4PhkAkpJQZJM0ca84QiixpcgzppyNjZ0rHa77AYl\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"ELChIHZqSD2FuNP2Om0HG58vq\", \"AccountName\": \"PenFj1H3OFxvapVxMkajspIgAvung1CXRe6zWYUqZ0ajHnFNqwnmQe3clu3lQtcocnaXAAgOGzNf4yEB9LEtggSNqWtCR68i68Yy\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"pgMFRWLfe9232yPoZmRxclPrW\", \"AccountName\": \"e8dmw84pm6V0rIX0at2oV2x3PxXdDMblXXdhrQlzwsyCMy470skYsDRx1HvmC04hGO2ooSou99p4Jxk03FSKjheyznypNRzFNGee\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"FuLwZuUxHk5qz7DbJKFaAk1nf\", \"AccountName\": \"xnr4LuXfYNwJCNTpAnAMqpSCUZJH2RsGgcYCIkoBvGCC0Y5G7nmGeefeMY1qiHqc9yYuZmA4td2YK11H95p9jmvsiMsR0mLzZcwP\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"9q6wUIpWptK2snHQl1oHOIDOh\", \"AccountName\": \"JGRsBJ4iZmo8jYMJWRhdwYCnaRSu0MTz0irlBv2H8uWQ6nmAymfwnmKBx4A2lbIITB2sGK6HZBGr08AOelhfQ2FSvZCvWR7fJplV\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"VPzvUi15dPCQz3JFXddY5lku7\", \"AccountName\": \"ZrC4MLimZhVntXHFbMtQXeRARhPGcxLOFMESD2UcStbJIooX4OYwn71z2rkzs8gHtTtrKBsn9JFX7mgXdPCYuCjPz656cl1YvuJO\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"pjKW2HvukzrTr4uUc5RkrQX9G\", \"AccountName\": \"K16DMwIt7Acy17UEehnvRjszsJPVAFX8eDAZAIXiPFlMxCfWgrHP0XHe0mI9u0bp3U04CIJxVKvCntg1iWBi5HLo1x2ePjDsywGK\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"40k46P7Af90lBD9Dxs90X9XbD\", \"AccountName\": \"YfUknDlydd3aI2YUVhiejam6PSDNkSgDXpSqUECyNgJ8BUE6vmmSLtoNVULnkLPsFSEeScc0GRY269GWEd9eBrbOF0UhWpq66Uo6\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"KGRLPzXL3CuCkjmXXTFX2Vy1C\", \"AccountName\": \"owCw4LHCwCAy9owmb2JWTF2jceSEcaG9l3YQXnhTDPQ2RAkdqfQd6kC87wNGo9lUEUKpGrCdqEGR4nXHdRk6pi7UjX6cKRLdjbJo\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"c8WbfMwFgpnSONGPMxfDodrqb\", \"AccountName\": \"8dqpyuncROeasZHA6C5dCscIWVWv2sGNHV4RO3yw5X1IATslKmEKIaey9hFYjKhzFlkkj85XfqVWuXml9dTaDFrW47UpIJ1wuH9O\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"Rl3nUxUqkoD7yLjUHoAdR9bVY\", \"AccountName\": \"16YHQgKFNaOw1DwDv2HwcaPg0JJtXgXwdeBlIyGANiPZaRLj210kaSBWzna7k4ECCsDqBQVcHpt9l9torigKAjVClazlfsfuqJ3P\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"MBV25amieTPrf8gI7M5FuC5bE\", \"AccountName\": \"P5E8mEabCiaxA8CTarZRGs2KXBtfB3hMh0vRRwKknHz6P4NxbziZMY9SM1byWCutlgh93RtIekNvF2z3Q60Z5nfiwESZwGYCbijR\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"Ls1EIZThlzSumkFmDBliWBzlQ\", \"AccountName\": \"Rf8Y7TJk2Uhi2hQSlSZtCbDyjN3Pkec7KUmcuJVmJX38dnC2qXYI4SPDd7OHwsgPwAzkbIu3FsG596V1Q9wbNf0quupgjEiCF4IR\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"gHh7NFfaZ5Hh4ojNuVWvWnvAS\", \"AccountName\": \"g5DJcwupGnfBfX5IcKuUa2XxjcW5tJnlZ8SLhKQVqD7o6SCjBhQl1lrinDOowI7bbFEo07Pl1sVKmCfuEjovvXdhPQTMG1uWphzn\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"tw8byaJbBt5VY4BWidVgCvsv8\", \"AccountName\": \"JpDVUBcigMe6xYjPaikqu4i4eUdT87zGOwUK40eE6vpvCFMMc8vMaXxfDfm6Rk6tddHNAyZ6tGKw5jgtInvumZxQNkOtRrXcmVbf\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"ZBFWeYjtJpR1S390nUtvWdkGa\", \"AccountName\": \"pSupMULccNRfbtz2NX3jasK6ZRIfsclkpxC1POOGX9qRcRcPk39YQK1x4Mg3grLRE6qJ5Wh9sSQHvDOBgvr5b7Gz512YVnbez3Pu\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"GpdAMTwJ4f5Mnf70feSibYu7Z\", \"AccountName\": \"7dka70foVMlK63NOE41zCi9laGEo6TZDUqejfM9koqgVVn11Dhw7VAslbnqICBC5QGCUosVhXkv4B0798yKSihccKiLJLZZGGJGL\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"8GnoLhRSI5l7XubwH7zonoV0z\", \"AccountName\": \"pR7qMCwRhuZYmHCgqOiGzkSJiutvzqIe90oeBbjaLx6cLGcSiHdFCRIYhelIzyaufVmpGsSvkuVKy4DU24OoduDKR6JuZb7AIBTq\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"EFzm5FnWYuuQ5HxFpI4Q5wrH1\", \"AccountName\": \"Pkq6pL3wIrKO6X02YWTFtE6kXHePsoZWm8hw3s5A6I4zfGNwcypcx5MuUnvLzFCZOndjCaz94ec42URYlIimYVQ14DUvKnUsFjzq\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"m6WsZghq1EPf9mXZ0IaApgtbq\", \"AccountName\": \"AYjcrGYO8dGS5COnHbj7QLvyboy0L146xuBT0YpsQtaBALxJvmqcJaYgoLb2cNyM3zkk5vJvaxgw7TyzbPeLgJ94kf7DfZmw9MMA\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"eFOOrXu9toQUXqja5wsBwORA3\", \"AccountName\": \"w4OJ3YTzGdedee3iivNXZjFlvImfdwtC6K0BzqVtCjibzkAeXXsHydW2RzdbJTeRo8JuMma0duxKZCaQO5UyQEP5iYLR0BNsrAuM\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"gboKdrpoj8quB88La3WkLvAMS\", \"AccountName\": \"Xzg4u8lQGTSc3vMbEm9deCJ4brEoK0EXo5e1YwRYvLsJoGcHQ10bTzx4WxzgOKbhKy65wzag813zW72oFGWUMxBD3WCfhWkiGEOv\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"hXCm0cnFrPq3QJWc9qDDL2wDk\", \"AccountName\": \"QLrKhYA745UjQAkVgIydB2rhtOl9QfZmYnLBWqyJDMxkYU3bS6omzVzL3ntvdgHvogrGK8um1VLeKzBslB1sq3KXEyw3k1jF6Zx8\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"Si3Mrv82IicpXJbeMEB1Ofbu7\", \"AccountName\": \"V72Bu0jYI25Y02auQoq0qVvdolUWNgsreLIVuHv9X6dZs6I071yFKIvKbyBgTclrAD18pQtQYpb5S8ni4Sd33Ro945qHb34ejM7k\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"l9AEIFFYcLjElvnocozQ3MIIv\", \"AccountName\": \"0wm2jR5020TmMOMUKU4KMFh5z3PCuXy5LeZvvMQ4t27BGQ3GJlz5sN1UlhVTsSULNMCLrtGz0yE5QPYioq0wep9ttAZgHOjPmgSd\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"f7igwEByBrdTXyOFfcZD6rjb3\", \"AccountName\": \"D2FuGQllhGIRO9mXjnhRE0yjKH53dsVYmGeKbY7iMxEJRQvY1bz0VtfIt5obxhFa5IzsBvDlokOQYaUbDaGQG67NfEpGd3I0QPdz\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"n8qKnkmk8hLH66mDCZF4pJdKl\", \"AccountName\": \"dcvy41VNCjpaJc2dlG0epKSUwyIKlKp8ek6nhpPdp6a1YEa4Wyi4jNqKMC6SgYU2nbJzgLAS6fwdsGKkcCDtmvJScMLh8BT1WgiN\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"zUB3tANSv7Hih7DLhoO95T5LU\", \"AccountName\": \"up10qGXMKGOh9I7NCD9haBwkIkYZALmgF9bwVh4fZWYivw5UWH4wGBZaN8rias9GXx22PaybsvIVV26iNRHrLGrlXtOB2nuOm2pF\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"jDQDjtGwzXbZwVuFo556Ia07Q\", \"AccountName\": \"r7F3QxkTzSjl5vyVsUIccW8SRHd9ouKdgzDle7y4Vkir7RQtMwATgnyoVuQ5Xl5v9VpcKYTKbcEFnhqdPZrpZrUHQfAOe6s1SacN\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"WWZGqpziMkAfLyJ3u8j5UJZtG\", \"AccountName\": \"5C4hcuuH9QAWHXqW3Z4jOj3s5E2KKCt7jiyeR4zpawrAmxuwCZMNN6VRW8PAiFzDQfrILyMiCkAODoVDHpYHnUgsvJ1YOX0mgPwn\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"McHrvxOzo7MWMR1qbau2pxzl2\", \"AccountName\": \"881Z5rZu3haucxes5UnU5eLFVBRyC2k7jP0voUlH4WvWOabjKSIx35A1mGSrN8sjFvERyEzSy5JnGjKYvBMZe5vhrasTCLOyRkzt\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"1S3liB34GuOYxdmtPBMLPi429\", \"AccountName\": \"DVoInZbROkE3SQcvqVJD8vKEFS4AiivWG2jGaJtjbbAXMdV5hW4uVQBTgLIhUacPWXZn9mjGSWacBv5Pa3fHrkmBxxXpw6Rdy2nJ\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"CRHS2ova2YL6lUTLBqeIwq8Yp\", \"AccountName\": \"tgVfh97rCt7E2lShg725zFZ5tikn7vgmjjVtAoJU6AI2AjKpxUmh7qc9RwJ5Xhviq1ESF490ETtDtCiJM1YmcRXCaAOQyBqTC55s\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"7OaTC9GwNFo4Tslvif9fjDypG\", \"AccountName\": \"jBm4yZJAhnma1YOEWy8o2mNxdX5nVIvY6BgEf0jLJubSGGufhGL51WHLdKe5A743VqiERPnwOmf2EVQpa2SMl3Skppt6VPs1TYBu\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"kfJKIpqRTXysXzQ05jPkS3mXY\", \"AccountName\": \"cHRqVlOqwZjOpx6RZkCRWEA4y554UEhLOc2IQknljD5P7OPmcrVuEk8jXI4y4MIzWp9JvEG92dqaBZBtMMgCu4fCnDMnou3F39Jb\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"k3jgUJRUxztzCTuKXbHl4HrwP\", \"AccountName\": \"0Tq4OTjRKiSRGRtyBP3iP0YNtBqkS4aBC6gRG4dNY46Xa4I1gGK9B5d8aGZLfkB2FpLJBSdj7t37QlCBEYxh1hMpjKw0uSotDXxf\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"vKAIBREZLMmXftaZbrH7TtOPp\", \"AccountName\": \"RScRUe1Ay0hBSFXeNa5Oj45C24Aon5IG71SGmSyPxNnhgufdWwbHiprEjAWp2NxalZ8vS7rs6zsCdejD8H8KUZ1D3LyAiClgzd1r\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"Jd8t2t91DtC0ZqsAuXysiY926\", \"AccountName\": \"Jce0LtDdLirR07dJsaZWDC6XGOPzbs7GggCpJho8hnnJg99ASyQqBK6fouDE5orEU08WB0I9hbzpKEz6XiXlRwYKmNfP9mZIIA9x\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"sIDjBc9JD7pwJdcdAYgxp9DiH\", \"AccountName\": \"GV3s4b75U2bxx2rLmERKO4aosqXAtfrdKvGDaw0FrUc5vzr9OPQrh7HUSjAj5tF8QcrBKbtQM6wBFoaJ1Am20IiuUo00U2YfBGMA\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"IVf7hSf9o97s5lDaZkc5DV8vB\", \"AccountName\": \"co0xnNJEGn5zyt62lSxZ2XVtlzOLnEO6Hx7ntCRpf2skGBilxUpAOrESQsVDY1mskKYxK8OcufJ9Ss7L9iJYnqlIOBhrv4FWvQzG\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"agBEcRAU0lksquhvW9HO5WYzX\", \"AccountName\": \"dK47e8zLSkVlHhQJM1TomQSD2XMIycJIfXZIkIudRqO7rc2Y2qNj8BThygA1FUW3hohD57tn6ShML6ZoP9rwxKSwGbx3GpXtPyh7\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"Ul27U3R3RtOZwJ07MScezLZYB\", \"AccountName\": \"lb7mTBT5hwhN3ZjzFpvQdR5EQxJ0vibrdSTQE4gyYMPrHBR6ZgCfXn3tcUgNKlXPFa25Ua95umzwfPHl6OpVHnekAIIZKouNJGsm\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"NXxKxn74xNxo1tvYoyX0YMo3R\", \"AccountName\": \"TtdZbqk7Ocogri5zg7xrr038VuOhRshM24JACIOnCuWmZZDEROlZCJUEbvst5m0JUQbvpzXipraVEMbSHPOrcu3b155Sm4heWlae\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"TucMslXICwfK8lNk0v3l7cenA\", \"AccountName\": \"S1mLbhzsfOXyJgRB1FkRJcSEEJmVa12rBZBEzS7gyqStKcufpTwqjBJYDB7miLKdrh6206XdhgJgYy81aiKWRmxEDk9wZs5kek99\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"uRWBStIAshw7Dx4Z1cRH3WpZN\", \"AccountName\": \"vXVs9mxkqSnqXeDOog94U7naRdCt5sdgPMqHV81wHg54oDjibvpdvZitsvy31AFuXqH49pgd1H3bzpdfaBwigJi471SM1w7jVNey\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"RpjqdK1xE2OZIsahW1diFY9vJ\", \"AccountName\": \"aavNJ7I63oXXn95Ign59S8K3ztk4LqrWpt32pi1vSsrfEwAMuQ1g1SPRS7U3WpoVnG0witLrqcorUnTggD3HywCoREKUaPaqiJ8P\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"vReSlUo3FEdPednr8UeKKHdMP\", \"AccountName\": \"Z2q9Rjf7ZIEOssh1QUmoWu8Nhep8PSn2ZUXXnEh9QiDdO3MxdmNspF6FsXF24DToFziwRjRzUERhwPYiWrQCIi4g5qu49QPg5SD4\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"JGlLOH6s79Mmc8FKjgVzFhT1e\", \"AccountName\": \"cI98yEyUhEJIMGAT29dKMHBGpYWazCpQOLk7VArIDrDno1HGFQPDdY5YXlNEXPsRiYYoQVJICalxXLl7brgsDk7prhIddYnzUT4m\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"v7RPh4RxjVAGls0gXNkN7zXf7\", \"AccountName\": \"Y7bvKYlKkXv38CHsiVfa5UC3JwdHm8aHkhN30toe55TXlBAc1I9G7Fn4Zt8LI9s0JsPfffL7Cka9SUPZ147xTsznEPAJ610XO3RO\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"eH94wS5kilOtD9wLtQdGB3Sde\", \"AccountName\": \"xY2uegNMQnap4MkRqLGbGCjvb5bfX4nbuQ7cp6smosNqeAfRDp5QduKJu8UHTg8P8zxjHroLRRCpYtWaMoRtxjEuwZ28lPQlYpuA\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"0aJZE7vQC7c9gTExp37j7ybqc\", \"AccountName\": \"brNYzlZWXWiWIEqtsoRzaDHqFvbyYV9IY4OlVQLH6A0EDiHMGkOmBOZdNO04Wxye7iHzqzkuEKabFR1FysDB2PsBFKvc50EU9oGU\"}, {\"AccountId\": \"JyleCugSqNexPGJgTS2Iegb6g\", \"AccountName\": \"1GY7ga6fEHZFLfn0i8T659oTkuvei3jKFo7krZIY12KReHfDCt80GNJEqaAZEBOk41UDRSHqEtnhoXlZkmHBV8VfrjxquNtGJcGm\"}]"}
```

Comment: The `Items` property appears to have a string representation of a JSON array rather than an actual JSON array.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Agreed but why? I do not see an error in the javascript.

Comment: test your jason on http://json2csharp.com/ - does it give you the except generated classes as AccountItemModel ? If not the json is incorrect or your models. The last " looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

I would like to put these references including the question that Christopher put it into the comments section here - some potential valuable references for other people who might see similar problems:

- [PrototypeJS version 1.6.0.2 Overrides JSON.parse and JSON.stringify and breaks socket.io functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236026/prototypejs-version-1-6-0-2-overrides-json-parse-and-json-stringify-and-breaks-s/21315324#21315324)
- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2339

#### Original answer

Some other library is probably overriding the default behaviour. See this question: [JSON.stringify() - Escaping Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774626/json-stringify-escaping-issue)

> It appears that an old version of Mootools in the header (v.1.2.4) was
> causing a conflict with JSON.stringify(). Apparently Mootools v1.2.4 tries to override JSON.stringify() with it's own alterations which are incorrect and in turn causes the issue with the backslash escaping.

Comment: Gave me something to look for but it does not appear that JSON.stringify has been modified as using the browser console JSON.stringify returns  ƒ stringify() { [native code] }

Comment: Are you using cefsharp?

Comment: I am and your answer got me pointed to the solution. Mootools isn't the only one to do it - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315324/73332 it turns out prototype does it as well so take your well earned points.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `"` before array start in your json string, I mean the `[` character
So your final json should look like this:

```
{"Items":[{"AccountId": "3O3RlhdhhzqWrQm1hCF1EoYpi", "AccountName": "MB6rsTTr7tUt74ccUnW2MS3pKta39wQuUaeKN1grgioqK4hI5D85eaiOwpXPdFecjZ2cIPaE7EZdTksA0ciWUvQk8eL18lu9EMzP"}, {"AccountId": "IvgAC4sYQTQ9NNJ8yBIsXaLst", "AccountName": "6xLU2M1gdGamb5oLQAAxhFQyBF8UrYn9WYiD4j7DA1lHUnwx01DDoK46IZqd0YSJT88AH5Z1JS8OQLx4Wb6TLfrQFglR21NlIQsz"}, {"AccountId": "vyrOHwHSwK1o4CPQ9IEP39Fyp", "AccountName": "Xg9mcZ0AxmtUS67bP0NSvRnKZsabldiDDKovDcGFYJkcM6yifqrYYmF9kqKH5Fz8C7REs85phuWD4m2kPL1qJJca8Q3svkdnfMiA"}, {"AccountId": "wIcYnNUNjGDCSfaD0YaQzAR0G", "AccountName": "177wc3wNIiGBdizzADu700PyltI3jOyHvVfETAWoz95P8hnIgrPswKf6xKEoBRQOjbt5PfTmtFFHxEv2gszcNrs0JfIjFv1yaiou"}, {"AccountId": "fLVRKU62qYgT5nmYaGrSNBoO8", "AccountName": "xTeqtRDv22YBJEa0oQJU6JQihfIvU0ywHiJGpd6D3vNYTWzvtpIZELYdsHpMyua9oWLFXpUuDvffhF7HTqrF9GtD9OmKy18aTJUh"}, {"AccountId": "460sbklroG9jq4BHCmpYEBg09", "AccountName": "6sLu7TjoZbJd7UKHPZNoBJUqbX7wfiHEvUzAHEIBfKvCG0GLowbXEB98jBP3Jdtzn7yFNAZGPJeEgbynn2Tn410tLsHRBAAmmb52"}, {"AccountId": "VoAwAepE8Nl2xvQzBS2382gFp", "AccountName": "JRCkTvrx8SC8S7K5yPltGy0KNWw5DpYzNAN9HiohMcg0OFVxio8JCM2IU2ZlbNYpSa9e9FzO19g3TSo0bovVlP0C6Kwzy3GJQQn7"}, {"AccountId": "nHLYxbly80bbIqgYEFGcRb3Kd", "AccountName": "ELFpJ0uuKJgg5nYMyQBFwhwzqX8VrsnWowZkVeSu4OKR7g5721AWYkBbJ8RauIVrXFq1g7iqgzzsOcsKRE1XrYWgnfttdPwne71s"}, {"AccountId": "uv9iHFJbodmJUhnoQAtLiDtrK", "AccountName": "4C8PYj6ZLLmkWz34ySVvb6BZZKN3virfyatFar6XmBaJIH9dvZy5xyT7hTZoExv6Cm7Xq9xvx0ndOHy4uXl9eq6JKDz1pos3l7zh"}, {"AccountId": "oYiHdoKtLkVh3tl0mfUDWrBTS", "AccountName": "ujpmv5RZ4azFefXJzPiIylHrPclrw5ftU6USj4kuXsO3xVSk8zJ1PR0pObBXoaakZYFSIdP2XRKms9ewHf285kZsu8lT9iunrGxt"}, {"AccountId": "LP5RQ8eHB5u5nf3hNBUHSswLc", "AccountName": "mpm4VRhaktsRsaipL2cy5ryJwreUig8PzE1Hc0zZS1SN2QGOve01JTI2ivJ545o1bH7rGy0nihEA7RtAdPPJDDsGCGmK1xGcl3N0"}, {"AccountId": "SfGZdWKC6LyeQarFvuLTrMtmL", "AccountName": "V28vnKp4RczlVI0qxFMVcEfrj7tfSh0DC5BoiAx8wSdUNZ8epdapiLEVWcPFkosMJ9ZEJ99pOh2QweqbjkN77AKRVbQyvIRV8p0M"}, {"AccountId": "FUde1uYkqtjYZAQ3DvV68THK6", "AccountName": "yVEJavfOaSv2sIQI5UgCUh7rdi8h2tl6qPEqTjLndcY33XwOktFbDojPZgprsz7RJK92urLMPMzQZy5VoS1ivu64l151tSscqEYd"}, {"AccountId": "6qyrcGz5bnKgKATtajjBT3yFt", "AccountName": "Uy58tA9VNI9WrIcX6dGidqCRTgXXmZCSnXjia53h055A2OnJhBoLDEKCH8cBZtjb6Z6Vn2ICqB8LUpnlUGre7UdYXpPif8TvQVwA"}, {"AccountId": "9DqjJxBNVtmNdGusXtW24yaBY", "AccountName": "RNPMbSecsRon6oO9csAYQZEP67In9P6yLaTuTcDECZKqrQ9MLiOBJrEw9PCasp5uC4oHZftYea7jmgo1J1T4xEFPIz5ILjhR4OF1"}, {"AccountId": "QSO0mm4GYETtzpMQAQaz39dpi", "AccountName": "735JP91332WTEXEfToHuNqIzMD4toOjCUiRcOFKYB9k2mVniNqrN9kLSE5O0XOAQoHm0ja3tYPm8eGDuLGFRNI2ZITJj4fZDjI51"}, {"AccountId": "0Wq6P76nNVprCHI5UR1JWgr4Y", "AccountName": "hjApFOp9voLOefSyVfZVhcOA2MuGaDm20kMgh8NcGfUhpeXv4T5JSYsAk3pCukIuSoxIliWgw5nxRtdKovwR2UL3dPbajsYOVKvn"}, {"AccountId": "uxzKcqZPdwzUiUO9I7FhwwmmU", "AccountName": "1LwmVFIZS64ICOJX13pe9kwztHLRZDoPiQ1j0sxglUT8rzSjqIKcTxNKBXfw6zbgjUct7DX7R8kbL42daOrLZbVenzKkcVTkzd0t"}, {"AccountId": "UKFHAvjg1Nui6DEbpUoVKHbLo", "AccountName": "M2WiPRgoaJMo9Prgw8EvB2yA4uG1qTJicWa3ZLB6uM13He9RmgOmyIerlOXj39V8NuZkfR7AsKMGxfTB0gg8EIZWEXeMJg9Aawid"}, {"AccountId": "DAMposuvLLPwTY3qXdNgedaX2", "AccountName": "WfvBbPAsmoePVWCczWh0dfKZQlK9c9dG0b5MY5wla9UJDcW1KkZBn91RJSh0sJsmx21CYa11tXSv6ZwmsOe4w8VOYizGLZPr9yUi"}, {"AccountId": "NJlRXVE5hnLWeX9QPov9zaoxc", "AccountName": "IuyVQ6TI2rY9WRwLl3KuLkhUehMo6jyDP2WXUNB6smpMLuDCIs6Wyq2EGitnj7Xc5Z6E86Es5uxue0oxBivWPXJFZHhhK1e5wn29"}, {"AccountId": "hOKA6PC251soOR1g7nNPqjUzK", "AccountName": "0aMMwfDhs8cAcU8RIqRLlPx45XFC27BbNLWB9fZJ7XbNvTlyNrUwBhw3a0zjMbOOKnIP5qVkAm89BW6GTUUdmDkcvENkshPsgAGd"}, {"AccountId": "RAnmleoMtGL30OufmRSbXVgyH", "AccountName": "E3gWhlUw774xWSNxyG0Ywzh6cmszOXELBMXs0uYItA7bZKC6vdiovdYm1mIWZjkbKmIGOJgJ0ZO1GNjZAvGikVpVF1IWpwg9tJwD"}, {"AccountId": "jS7jx8TkggDmv8E7UzDaFc5TE", "AccountName": "4YStCcm3jmaITyae5OW0OcyFlQU8asPyydYtwsfERm0R1aKglzNWTazrZ0cC18cZBCYsXkFs5yyI7HC3NoGXrmSKr7YIJPxKIzK1"}, {"AccountId": "QiMB5SrwDKhW1OMrE4TbfdpAU", "AccountName": "lJTzjtFRF0rpBSuhym2RbdLyZ2paMqXivI8ba9IUPLKxUvZbWu4u6LmozHkMpy718EQU7zjsV1qMx4y2cw3oGNjUe8wAj96twaip"}, {"AccountId": "oP1KRoqcyae9708r5RI30ZlPb", "AccountName": "3az6FzT2qPreZ64NOieRhLHy2J7mzTJVQIENfJjRR5yCKNVQQaSu7DAIrzdiwiJte59Nf9kfFJTBjcO3WZpfGwfsnLqwe3qKO11g"}, {"AccountId": "cM7VtnzbgPME8f2awF0pE7QyU", "AccountName": "p15n5dVcqlw42dFTAKjgF7B6E8g6k95hlqgtzlxSqaSpepCpM9fdSJ2ntApWkcHkORnVkIXxcSBYTVm9frUB5FAXAgG21LAHI5dl"}, {"AccountId": "6CS2YyDQyQs2zNSmiMtUCIPsZ", "AccountName": "lx3YJ3IejKn9uGcAKQaHC9xOL9LCXzbGRaR0dEf78wX1CPw245ukrGpRghH9XMkJFephSdMvGZxvjEW9fZAz83oKtYpg79XUFOtu"}, {"AccountId": "X6UedJHy07iVAkmAPA9jN200g", "AccountName": "NLVWy3DxuwtVs0pOZnvjyI5b8WVFqVB0Gu3d9KxhcvxT0VtAOoD7K2F4jcaaa6t2yqEpbTKgUqpqtXtQ0O2omiFX12lPvBz9wFPv"}, {"AccountId": "b3XyVzQFj2rrns3qx0ZOychx1", "AccountName": "pMxDS1h9FSyONeaC8cYDEA7dcrtwzcnRTOwwDmFXAwdZdsmrTwEBRzNGIcbpDJBpFJhTL6eL6t3VZN0zvC4hxEN4JmSO23p2hU5e"}, {"AccountId": "eXaE87vsepubVJ1zIzuYInmix", "AccountName": "2da7G5qf0cU6zfUDLo8MzcswVvPXToSiVvozOcMehIdYShzCba45kxnExFn5rFAExF2rLGTzww3jJOFfF4l1sh28EgfRFR9qUQhf"}, {"AccountId": "cKdL80sMFttp5ErKsm1e9nEBg", "AccountName": "hbbA0byasvExllqzR6utPxsNjNOkGgd2HI58mzNnJJL9okvxBpLJHDZyMM0kQQEfnRG1E8aenxWGsFqmy4XJDvQ3xECdU678bIUS"}, {"AccountId": "Z5HnWwFGweGsI5w9w3zX6qG9E", "AccountName": "ydeAGvMKp1l7MOYpszgR4KmdINTIU2u9zYUbQ2M1YR6WkAtSRYqx61nHPdmph9aAwNKfV26blGgfMZgC8OguPSd0lV4n9GgBihAm"}, {"AccountId": "WSkDp58ltar8Gou5USLCBqJLV", "AccountName": "wUWx0caPh5ZntHxT3MhiB9PugTcDBmcSmRyLXrYiBfZZPWv7n89qeIS7V5nIH5nNsefzprbkhTWRLxrmMpVEscF0ASa60KvVTLo7"}, {"AccountId": "15Ns40cnHYe0A9AKREQ60OKMb", "AccountName": "WXFpnhG42pkg86VnPjZMwHGIn8yWZ3KPR8NyQjH3YKFMzTsojytw5EMUTFfE8m7A6AYXMNJpHFDqnbh3EiPzPfu8XRHdkUq7yXrS"}, {"AccountId": "nxSwRKd7tR7YzZZtbplb70bJb", "AccountName": "pjHmBu5eVCasoo5KEY3jVloNcnpjMY9KDEy05ibJhyE99mHLMWCd4avsyxZb3xqO7CUeS7LZBzp6dpeve4vaZcVnAp5QZ048y4e7"}, {"AccountId": "Ev1hP7wEJ5Q8WwKhrrxAQYT5i", "AccountName": "MoHupEDFk1HgWOLSHov9oYdtlvZNBvrEE0oY6xjf3fxZbU2Xl4xMxuputlGtjYhkmVpyjvUWjytwtZxIopNFuA22HahnDatKQo4a"}, {"AccountId": "ypymBjkGwPxHZTEqDHMBIgJUS", "AccountName": "vbNxBsStMJWIowgVBXqPsI1unFXrOjX1G61Th9eDMIzgGt0JxlpAKbqulj3ZDyuNl5xMqgY8hGPER9YI13aUp7TwcqqGM5cjza8u"}, {"AccountId": "GVQ56gL1ccJ5atXE7kM7peN2w", "AccountName": "x5d4OPUWFXnBhGq2UiNYE2hgvWDlkeill3WgwTtps9YT8fPjOM1bsxtyeE9FOpFnN0sjDApwBWajBh0S8NfKlP1vgMi1tJjx9mtE"}, {"AccountId": "gquwT7QOmuiKs2NzRkVFsYw6h", "AccountName": "A2gNMofHqC11WD4abTvKIU2RoXjGPrk0AwMVnTup1hEuzpydYgVRBPScKYvdoienlkhwaydZZjJn9knsfDFulIsTtDiy0A7b3bpa"}, {"AccountId": "6ef3yRIX4OMPPgA1tDeaW8GDz", "AccountName": "zpjzYHobfGt9F0xaW4c4sIlEyboJdD5lQUvDM4o8qutNe1OE4BoZUbWlzUrkJjlMKoyaVz9PQiauAmShWXMYC6ymE4GGQVD3ajBA"}, {"AccountId": "mu8iaBu5SAYMQxVdVtCXcHsBV", "AccountName": "eJ17K6BCtRbtWtJ1xRlRSp2sAH3VhJgXG4T769w5VjLs9rQnzZgaVqbg5hDdUhVKWIRXuvD7R2aScDwtTyKZ2IUV4djiv8kYIQNZ"}, {"AccountId": "JVID8ZI6bvcaeD9diLjPO7gIN", "AccountName": "KnMcOFfE37dafZEa05Dt2kdpuvoRCNPJndYDwgRR78RuYnHlVNLKODRek7vcxErkj3zmu5NxAmKjjnE6JbGVtfvHhZxHM5g3fRan"}, {"AccountId": "NUag1wRmvYacugJipQDALGDkR", "AccountName": "bt2uVbLwI3A249MH72WnJfHGyHY091fi2aSqSEwjhpZqGlKRZb0DkVCqYBilsHsjNRM1q7AbJrPh73N109L2YbPMcA1fzYgJtGAQ"}, {"AccountId": "tHlsGcE0Yq67hQw73sbDVfAGO", "AccountName": "eAbi61uxE310CcBh2I2d8Rm8xLVTsrvPHTDg7M2a5BFiXq96b9itxk0ECMcx4PhkAkpJQZJM0ca84QiixpcgzppyNjZ0rHa77AYl"}, {"AccountId": "ELChIHZqSD2FuNP2Om0HG58vq", "AccountName": "PenFj1H3OFxvapVxMkajspIgAvung1CXRe6zWYUqZ0ajHnFNqwnmQe3clu3lQtcocnaXAAgOGzNf4yEB9LEtggSNqWtCR68i68Yy"}, {"AccountId": "pgMFRWLfe9232yPoZmRxclPrW", "AccountName": "e8dmw84pm6V0rIX0at2oV2x3PxXdDMblXXdhrQlzwsyCMy470skYsDRx1HvmC04hGO2ooSou99p4Jxk03FSKjheyznypNRzFNGee"}, {"AccountId": "FuLwZuUxHk5qz7DbJKFaAk1nf", "AccountName": "xnr4LuXfYNwJCNTpAnAMqpSCUZJH2RsGgcYCIkoBvGCC0Y5G7nmGeefeMY1qiHqc9yYuZmA4td2YK11H95p9jmvsiMsR0mLzZcwP"}, {"AccountId": "9q6wUIpWptK2snHQl1oHOIDOh", "AccountName": "JGRsBJ4iZmo8jYMJWRhdwYCnaRSu0MTz0irlBv2H8uWQ6nmAymfwnmKBx4A2lbIITB2sGK6HZBGr08AOelhfQ2FSvZCvWR7fJplV"}, {"AccountId": "VPzvUi15dPCQz3JFXddY5lku7", "AccountName": "ZrC4MLimZhVntXHFbMtQXeRARhPGcxLOFMESD2UcStbJIooX4OYwn71z2rkzs8gHtTtrKBsn9JFX7mgXdPCYuCjPz656cl1YvuJO"}, {"AccountId": "pjKW2HvukzrTr4uUc5RkrQX9G", "AccountName": "K16DMwIt7Acy17UEehnvRjszsJPVAFX8eDAZAIXiPFlMxCfWgrHP0XHe0mI9u0bp3U04CIJxVKvCntg1iWBi5HLo1x2ePjDsywGK"}, {"AccountId": "40k46P7Af90lBD9Dxs90X9XbD", "AccountName": "YfUknDlydd3aI2YUVhiejam6PSDNkSgDXpSqUECyNgJ8BUE6vmmSLtoNVULnkLPsFSEeScc0GRY269GWEd9eBrbOF0UhWpq66Uo6"}, {"AccountId": "KGRLPzXL3CuCkjmXXTFX2Vy1C", "AccountName": "owCw4LHCwCAy9owmb2JWTF2jceSEcaG9l3YQXnhTDPQ2RAkdqfQd6kC87wNGo9lUEUKpGrCdqEGR4nXHdRk6pi7UjX6cKRLdjbJo"}, {"AccountId": "c8WbfMwFgpnSONGPMxfDodrqb", "AccountName": "8dqpyuncROeasZHA6C5dCscIWVWv2sGNHV4RO3yw5X1IATslKmEKIaey9hFYjKhzFlkkj85XfqVWuXml9dTaDFrW47UpIJ1wuH9O"}, {"AccountId": "Rl3nUxUqkoD7yLjUHoAdR9bVY", "AccountName": "16YHQgKFNaOw1DwDv2HwcaPg0JJtXgXwdeBlIyGANiPZaRLj210kaSBWzna7k4ECCsDqBQVcHpt9l9torigKAjVClazlfsfuqJ3P"}, {"AccountId": "MBV25amieTPrf8gI7M5FuC5bE", "AccountName": "P5E8mEabCiaxA8CTarZRGs2KXBtfB3hMh0vRRwKknHz6P4NxbziZMY9SM1byWCutlgh93RtIekNvF2z3Q60Z5nfiwESZwGYCbijR"}, {"AccountId": "Ls1EIZThlzSumkFmDBliWBzlQ", "AccountName": "Rf8Y7TJk2Uhi2hQSlSZtCbDyjN3Pkec7KUmcuJVmJX38dnC2qXYI4SPDd7OHwsgPwAzkbIu3FsG596V1Q9wbNf0quupgjEiCF4IR"}, {"AccountId": "gHh7NFfaZ5Hh4ojNuVWvWnvAS", "AccountName": "g5DJcwupGnfBfX5IcKuUa2XxjcW5tJnlZ8SLhKQVqD7o6SCjBhQl1lrinDOowI7bbFEo07Pl1sVKmCfuEjovvXdhPQTMG1uWphzn"}, {"AccountId": "tw8byaJbBt5VY4BWidVgCvsv8", "AccountName": "JpDVUBcigMe6xYjPaikqu4i4eUdT87zGOwUK40eE6vpvCFMMc8vMaXxfDfm6Rk6tddHNAyZ6tGKw5jgtInvumZxQNkOtRrXcmVbf"}, {"AccountId": "ZBFWeYjtJpR1S390nUtvWdkGa", "AccountName": "pSupMULccNRfbtz2NX3jasK6ZRIfsclkpxC1POOGX9qRcRcPk39YQK1x4Mg3grLRE6qJ5Wh9sSQHvDOBgvr5b7Gz512YVnbez3Pu"}, {"AccountId": "GpdAMTwJ4f5Mnf70feSibYu7Z", "AccountName": "7dka70foVMlK63NOE41zCi9laGEo6TZDUqejfM9koqgVVn11Dhw7VAslbnqICBC5QGCUosVhXkv4B0798yKSihccKiLJLZZGGJGL"}, {"AccountId": "8GnoLhRSI5l7XubwH7zonoV0z", "AccountName": "pR7qMCwRhuZYmHCgqOiGzkSJiutvzqIe90oeBbjaLx6cLGcSiHdFCRIYhelIzyaufVmpGsSvkuVKy4DU24OoduDKR6JuZb7AIBTq"}, {"AccountId": "EFzm5FnWYuuQ5HxFpI4Q5wrH1", "AccountName": "Pkq6pL3wIrKO6X02YWTFtE6kXHePsoZWm8hw3s5A6I4zfGNwcypcx5MuUnvLzFCZOndjCaz94ec42URYlIimYVQ14DUvKnUsFjzq"}, {"AccountId": "m6WsZghq1EPf9mXZ0IaApgtbq", "AccountName": "AYjcrGYO8dGS5COnHbj7QLvyboy0L146xuBT0YpsQtaBALxJvmqcJaYgoLb2cNyM3zkk5vJvaxgw7TyzbPeLgJ94kf7DfZmw9MMA"}, {"AccountId": "eFOOrXu9toQUXqja5wsBwORA3", "AccountName": "w4OJ3YTzGdedee3iivNXZjFlvImfdwtC6K0BzqVtCjibzkAeXXsHydW2RzdbJTeRo8JuMma0duxKZCaQO5UyQEP5iYLR0BNsrAuM"}, {"AccountId": "gboKdrpoj8quB88La3WkLvAMS", "AccountName": "Xzg4u8lQGTSc3vMbEm9deCJ4brEoK0EXo5e1YwRYvLsJoGcHQ10bTzx4WxzgOKbhKy65wzag813zW72oFGWUMxBD3WCfhWkiGEOv"}, {"AccountId": "hXCm0cnFrPq3QJWc9qDDL2wDk", "AccountName": "QLrKhYA745UjQAkVgIydB2rhtOl9QfZmYnLBWqyJDMxkYU3bS6omzVzL3ntvdgHvogrGK8um1VLeKzBslB1sq3KXEyw3k1jF6Zx8"}, {"AccountId": "Si3Mrv82IicpXJbeMEB1Ofbu7", "AccountName": "V72Bu0jYI25Y02auQoq0qVvdolUWNgsreLIVuHv9X6dZs6I071yFKIvKbyBgTclrAD18pQtQYpb5S8ni4Sd33Ro945qHb34ejM7k"}, {"AccountId": "l9AEIFFYcLjElvnocozQ3MIIv", "AccountName": "0wm2jR5020TmMOMUKU4KMFh5z3PCuXy5LeZvvMQ4t27BGQ3GJlz5sN1UlhVTsSULNMCLrtGz0yE5QPYioq0wep9ttAZgHOjPmgSd"}, {"AccountId": "f7igwEByBrdTXyOFfcZD6rjb3", "AccountName": "D2FuGQllhGIRO9mXjnhRE0yjKH53dsVYmGeKbY7iMxEJRQvY1bz0VtfIt5obxhFa5IzsBvDlokOQYaUbDaGQG67NfEpGd3I0QPdz"}, {"AccountId": "n8qKnkmk8hLH66mDCZF4pJdKl", "AccountName": "dcvy41VNCjpaJc2dlG0epKSUwyIKlKp8ek6nhpPdp6a1YEa4Wyi4jNqKMC6SgYU2nbJzgLAS6fwdsGKkcCDtmvJScMLh8BT1WgiN"}, {"AccountId": "zUB3tANSv7Hih7DLhoO95T5LU", "AccountName": "up10qGXMKGOh9I7NCD9haBwkIkYZALmgF9bwVh4fZWYivw5UWH4wGBZaN8rias9GXx22PaybsvIVV26iNRHrLGrlXtOB2nuOm2pF"}, {"AccountId": "jDQDjtGwzXbZwVuFo556Ia07Q", "AccountName": "r7F3QxkTzSjl5vyVsUIccW8SRHd9ouKdgzDle7y4Vkir7RQtMwATgnyoVuQ5Xl5v9VpcKYTKbcEFnhqdPZrpZrUHQfAOe6s1SacN"}, {"AccountId": "WWZGqpziMkAfLyJ3u8j5UJZtG", "AccountName": "5C4hcuuH9QAWHXqW3Z4jOj3s5E2KKCt7jiyeR4zpawrAmxuwCZMNN6VRW8PAiFzDQfrILyMiCkAODoVDHpYHnUgsvJ1YOX0mgPwn"}, {"AccountId": "McHrvxOzo7MWMR1qbau2pxzl2", "AccountName": "881Z5rZu3haucxes5UnU5eLFVBRyC2k7jP0voUlH4WvWOabjKSIx35A1mGSrN8sjFvERyEzSy5JnGjKYvBMZe5vhrasTCLOyRkzt"}, {"AccountId": "1S3liB34GuOYxdmtPBMLPi429", "AccountName": "DVoInZbROkE3SQcvqVJD8vKEFS4AiivWG2jGaJtjbbAXMdV5hW4uVQBTgLIhUacPWXZn9mjGSWacBv5Pa3fHrkmBxxXpw6Rdy2nJ"}, {"AccountId": "CRHS2ova2YL6lUTLBqeIwq8Yp", "AccountName": "tgVfh97rCt7E2lShg725zFZ5tikn7vgmjjVtAoJU6AI2AjKpxUmh7qc9RwJ5Xhviq1ESF490ETtDtCiJM1YmcRXCaAOQyBqTC55s"}, {"AccountId": "7OaTC9GwNFo4Tslvif9fjDypG", "AccountName": "jBm4yZJAhnma1YOEWy8o2mNxdX5nVIvY6BgEf0jLJubSGGufhGL51WHLdKe5A743VqiERPnwOmf2EVQpa2SMl3Skppt6VPs1TYBu"}, {"AccountId": "kfJKIpqRTXysXzQ05jPkS3mXY", "AccountName": "cHRqVlOqwZjOpx6RZkCRWEA4y554UEhLOc2IQknljD5P7OPmcrVuEk8jXI4y4MIzWp9JvEG92dqaBZBtMMgCu4fCnDMnou3F39Jb"}, {"AccountId": "k3jgUJRUxztzCTuKXbHl4HrwP", "AccountName": "0Tq4OTjRKiSRGRtyBP3iP0YNtBqkS4aBC6gRG4dNY46Xa4I1gGK9B5d8aGZLfkB2FpLJBSdj7t37QlCBEYxh1hMpjKw0uSotDXxf"}, {"AccountId": "vKAIBREZLMmXftaZbrH7TtOPp", "AccountName": "RScRUe1Ay0hBSFXeNa5Oj45C24Aon5IG71SGmSyPxNnhgufdWwbHiprEjAWp2NxalZ8vS7rs6zsCdejD8H8KUZ1D3LyAiClgzd1r"}, {"AccountId": "Jd8t2t91DtC0ZqsAuXysiY926", "AccountName": "Jce0LtDdLirR07dJsaZWDC6XGOPzbs7GggCpJho8hnnJg99ASyQqBK6fouDE5orEU08WB0I9hbzpKEz6XiXlRwYKmNfP9mZIIA9x"}, {"AccountId": "sIDjBc9JD7pwJdcdAYgxp9DiH", "AccountName": "GV3s4b75U2bxx2rLmERKO4aosqXAtfrdKvGDaw0FrUc5vzr9OPQrh7HUSjAj5tF8QcrBKbtQM6wBFoaJ1Am20IiuUo00U2YfBGMA"}, {"AccountId": "IVf7hSf9o97s5lDaZkc5DV8vB", "AccountName": "co0xnNJEGn5zyt62lSxZ2XVtlzOLnEO6Hx7ntCRpf2skGBilxUpAOrESQsVDY1mskKYxK8OcufJ9Ss7L9iJYnqlIOBhrv4FWvQzG"}, {"AccountId": "agBEcRAU0lksquhvW9HO5WYzX", "AccountName": "dK47e8zLSkVlHhQJM1TomQSD2XMIycJIfXZIkIudRqO7rc2Y2qNj8BThygA1FUW3hohD57tn6ShML6ZoP9rwxKSwGbx3GpXtPyh7"}, {"AccountId": "Ul27U3R3RtOZwJ07MScezLZYB", "AccountName": "lb7mTBT5hwhN3ZjzFpvQdR5EQxJ0vibrdSTQE4gyYMPrHBR6ZgCfXn3tcUgNKlXPFa25Ua95umzwfPHl6OpVHnekAIIZKouNJGsm"}, {"AccountId": "NXxKxn74xNxo1tvYoyX0YMo3R", "AccountName": "TtdZbqk7Ocogri5zg7xrr038VuOhRshM24JACIOnCuWmZZDEROlZCJUEbvst5m0JUQbvpzXipraVEMbSHPOrcu3b155Sm4heWlae"}, {"AccountId": "TucMslXICwfK8lNk0v3l7cenA", "AccountName": "S1mLbhzsfOXyJgRB1FkRJcSEEJmVa12rBZBEzS7gyqStKcufpTwqjBJYDB7miLKdrh6206XdhgJgYy81aiKWRmxEDk9wZs5kek99"}, {"AccountId": "uRWBStIAshw7Dx4Z1cRH3WpZN", "AccountName": "vXVs9mxkqSnqXeDOog94U7naRdCt5sdgPMqHV81wHg54oDjibvpdvZitsvy31AFuXqH49pgd1H3bzpdfaBwigJi471SM1w7jVNey"}, {"AccountId": "RpjqdK1xE2OZIsahW1diFY9vJ", "AccountName": "aavNJ7I63oXXn95Ign59S8K3ztk4LqrWpt32pi1vSsrfEwAMuQ1g1SPRS7U3WpoVnG0witLrqcorUnTggD3HywCoREKUaPaqiJ8P"}, {"AccountId": "vReSlUo3FEdPednr8UeKKHdMP", "AccountName": "Z2q9Rjf7ZIEOssh1QUmoWu8Nhep8PSn2ZUXXnEh9QiDdO3MxdmNspF6FsXF24DToFziwRjRzUERhwPYiWrQCIi4g5qu49QPg5SD4"}, {"AccountId": "JGlLOH6s79Mmc8FKjgVzFhT1e", "AccountName": "cI98yEyUhEJIMGAT29dKMHBGpYWazCpQOLk7VArIDrDno1HGFQPDdY5YXlNEXPsRiYYoQVJICalxXLl7brgsDk7prhIddYnzUT4m"}, {"AccountId": "v7RPh4RxjVAGls0gXNkN7zXf7", "AccountName": "Y7bvKYlKkXv38CHsiVfa5UC3JwdHm8aHkhN30toe55TXlBAc1I9G7Fn4Zt8LI9s0JsPfffL7Cka9SUPZ147xTsznEPAJ610XO3RO"}, {"AccountId": "eH94wS5kilOtD9wLtQdGB3Sde", "AccountName": "xY2uegNMQnap4MkRqLGbGCjvb5bfX4nbuQ7cp6smosNqeAfRDp5QduKJu8UHTg8P8zxjHroLRRCpYtWaMoRtxjEuwZ28lPQlYpuA"}, {"AccountId": "0aJZE7vQC7c9gTExp37j7ybqc", "AccountName": "brNYzlZWXWiWIEqtsoRzaDHqFvbyYV9IY4OlVQLH6A0EDiHMGkOmBOZdNO04Wxye7iHzqzkuEKabFR1FysDB2PsBFKvc50EU9oGU"}, {"AccountId": "JyleCugSqNexPGJgTS2Iegb6g", "AccountName": "1GY7ga6fEHZFLfn0i8T659oTkuvei3jKFo7krZIY12KReHfDCt80GNJEqaAZEBOk41UDRSHqEtnhoXlZkmHBV8VfrjxquNtGJcGm"}]}
```

And if you want an escaped string, you can replace all `"` character with `\"`

Comment: OK, but why is the browser native JSON.stringify returning the incorrect result. Is it  a bug in the browser, in this case Chromium, or an error in my data structure/logic?

Comment: Actually, I don't know why `stringify` is returning that result but you can validate your json [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), where it does not validate yours but it validate if you remove the extra `"`

Comment: it is not "my" json it is the direct output of JSON.stringify